# NodeJS Cambiar Codificación fichero

Tags: nodejs

necesito cambiar la codificación de un fichero XML que se encuentra en UTF16-BE a UTF-8 para poder parsearlo con el modulo xml2j.
He probado a utilizar el modulo inconv (https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv), pero no me lo hace, me sale que el contenido del buffer es null.

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
  var fs = require("fs");
  var input = fs.readFileSync(path);
  var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
  var output = iconv.decode(input, "UTF-16BE");
 //fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
  parser.parseString(output, function (err, result) {
       console.log(output );
        console.dir(result);
        console.log("se ha parseado el XML");
        return result;
    });
```

Siendo el resultado por consola:

```
vamos a parsear el xml
    null
    null
    se ha parseado el XML
```

¿existe algún otro modo de realizar el cambio de codificación del fichero?

Comment: La variable **err** también viene vacia?

Comment: Podrías tambien intentar con el módulo **encoding**. https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding

Comment: Sí, err también está vacía. He actualizado la primera publicación.

Comment: Probe el código que pones y me funcionó bien. Cree un xml con la codificación que especificas y el resultado fue el esperado. Quizas tenga que ver con la versión del módulo que usas o el contenido del fichero que tratas de convertir.

Comment: Sí, @devconcept, tenías razón, era un problema del fichero a convertir.
Gracias a todos por la ayuda